# Error launching Inkscape

Tags: 20.04, permissions, inkscape

I'm trying to launch Inkscape 1.2 (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS) from the console and is throwing this error:

```
Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Permission denied (g-file-error-quark, 2)
```

I also tried to launch it as root, but it also failed due to permissions sending this error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
No protocol specified
```

I installed through Software app and it's been working until now.

Any idea was going on and how to fix this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: How did you install Inkscape (from where, with which commands)?

Comment: Installed through Software app.

Comment: The current version of Inkscape (in 20.04.4 LTS) is 0.92.5 according to `apt-cache policy inkscape`. Please check that you have that version. That is the version available via classic repository. Is your version 1.2 installed via snap? Anyway, try to remove the version you have and install 0.92.5 with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install inkscape`; I can launch it, and I think it should work for you too.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the current version and installed 0.92.5 and it's working.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad I could help you :-)